# App not open – always redirect

Tags: branch.io

I am trying to use branch.io with android application. My main task is start application by link and pass some parameters in application. I took values for ‘scheme’, ‘…BranchKey’ and ‘…BranchKey.test’ and replaced them in the sample [Branch-SDK-TestBed][1]. Now after i click link I get redirect on page with message “It seems like you havn’t properly set up your branch link”. But all works good if old values are returned. Please help with my problem. Thank you.

Comment: please do some proper format and add some codes where you have problem.

Answer (score 0):

Alex from Branch.io here:

Hi! This message means you need to go to the [link settings page](https://dashboard.branch.io/settings/link) on the Branch dashboard and enter the required values. These values are tied to your Branch key, so when you use the original Branch key from the TestBed app, everything works because we have already set up all those values. Your new replacement Branch key doesn't have these defined yet, leading to the error.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!
Would you point me what is wrong with my settings?
These are my android link settings: [screenshot](https://s32.postimg.org/j2suif5ad/settings.png). 
Value for ‘Android URI Scheme’ is entered but links behave as described above.

Comment: You need a fallback value in the field that has an orange outline. If your app isn't available in the Play Store yet, then you can select 'Custom URL' and put in something temporary.